# 2D Array in PHP Fails When Trying to Find Matching String

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, count

I'm still learning PHP, but I needed a way of keeping track of a list of two associated values, a cinema and its postcode. Now before you read any further I must stress that I do not technically need this problem solving as I have since replaced it with a more efficient method. I'm really just wanting to know why it *doesn't* work as I can't find anything about it elsewhere.

```
$cinema_locations = array(
    array("Odeon", "M4 2BS"),
    array("Cineworld", "OL7 0PG"),
    array("Vue", "M50 3AG"),
    array("AMC", "M3 4EN")
);
for ($i=0; $i<count($cinema_locations); $i++) {
    if ($cinema_locations[$i][0] == $_GET['cinema_name']) {
        $postcode = $cinema_locations[$i][1];
        return;
    }
}
```

As you can probably tell from the code, I am trying to loop through the main array so that I may compare the first value of each child array against a `$_GET` variable. I have checked over this code multiple times and even showed some of my other coder friends and none of us can find anything wrong, syntax or otherwise. And yet, the browser shows only a white screen. If anyone can shed some light on the issue, I and my friends would be most appreciative; and who knows, it may help someone else with the same issue.

For anyone that may be curious, I replaced the 2D array with an associative array thus:

```
$cinema_locations = array(
    "Odeon" => "M4 2BS",
    "Cineworld" => "OL7 0PG",
    "Vue" => "M50 3AG",
    "AMC" => "M3 4EN"
);
$postcode = $cinema_locations[$_GET['cinema_name']];
```

> EDIT

Thanks rishi, that did it. I never even considered that the `return` would nullify the result. Using `break` stopped the loop and the rest of the page loaded fine.

Comment: Well, if that's all your code does (assign a value to $postcode, then return null), then you'll obviously end up with nothing. What are you even supposed to do with that variable?

Comment: use in_array function find value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you should write `break;` instead of `return;`

You needed to `break` your for loop if you meet the condition. and continue with the below code.

`return` will instantly returns value from where its called.

Answer (score 1):

For situations in which you cannot change the array structure, this code is a better approach.

```
// same array as the original post
$cinema_locations = array(
    array("Odeon", "M4 2BS"),
    array("Cineworld", "OL7 0PG"),
    array("Vue", "M50 3AG"),
    array("AMC", "M3 4EN")
);

foreach ($cinema_locations as $c_loc) {
    $postcode = ($_GET'cinema_name'] == $c_loc[0]) ? $c_loc[1] : null;
}

print $postcode;
```

Of course, you should never use `$_GET` directly like this, but you probably already knew that.

Comment: Good to know. I haven't much experience with using the abbreviated then/else but I suppose I should learn. And yes, I know about the insecurities of using `$_GET` this way, this is just for my college assignment, all on a local server.

Comment: @Alek ternary operators, lambda functions, array mapping functions... PHP offers a wide array of things to simplify coding with.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind. I only started learning it two months ago so I'm still learning.

Comment: @Alek good luck, but do switch to using a framework like Symfony or Laravel as soon as possible.